# How to calculate determinant matrix with lapack++ (2.5+)

Tags: c++, lapack++

What is the best (fastest) way to calculate the determinant of a (non symmetric, squared) [LaMatGenDouble](http://lapackpp.sourceforge.net/html/classLaGenMatDouble.html) matrix with the [lapack++](http://lapackpp.sourceforge.net/) library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to calculate the determinant is using the LU decomposition:

```
  LaVectorLongInt pivots(A.cols());

  LUFactorizeIP(A, pivots);

  double detA = 1;
  for (int i = 0; i < A.cols(); ++i)
    detA *= A(i, i);
```

Warning, **A** will change, so making a copy is probably advised.

Comment: I accepted this answer now as the accepted one, because no other options have been provided. If somebody adds another (good, acceptable) solution, I will accept that answer.

Comment: I think you also need a negative sign if you have an odd number of permutations (pivots size is odd). See also: http://icl.cs.utk.edu/lapack-forum/viewtopic.php?p=341&#p336

Comment: The factorization is `A = PLU`. Here L has ones on the diagonal, so `det(L)=1`. Now `det(A) = det(P)*det(L)*det(U) = det(P)*1*det(U)`. In the code above the sign of the permuation matrix `P` (represented as an array of pivots) are not handled.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about lapack++ but I'm sure there isn't in standard lapack, [check](http://web.mit.edu/lapack_v3.0-06/www/lapackfaq.html#1.16). As far as I know lapack++ does not implement the matricial operation itself but uses others', actually you can switch between several of them (atlas, mkl (intel math kernel library) and so on). Therefore my assumption is that there is any determinant operation in lapack++ either.

Comment: Lapack++ contains all BLAS operations. There is no determinant function in BLAS, but there are probably other methods that can be used to obtain the determinant.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your question. I deserved the bad karma :-) .